# C++ - getaddrinfo() - getting own external IP with dynamic dns fails

Tags: c++, dynamic, dns, getaddrinfo

I'm currently working on a program that tells me, among other things, my external IP. To achieve this, I'm using the function `getaddrinfo()`.
For testing purpose I passed `google.com` as node name, it worked fine.
If I'm passing my dynamic dns to the function, I receive `0.0.0.0` as IP, but I'm expecting my own external IP. I also tried a dynamic dns from a friend with the same result.
As far as I can get the IP from `google.com`, the problem shouldn't be my code.
**Is it not possible, to receive the IP from a dynamic dns with `getaddrinfo()` or is there anything else I'm doing wrong?**

**Edit:**

```
WSADATA wsaD {};
addrinfo hints = {AI_NON_AUTHORITATIVE, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
addrinfo *infoAddress;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaD);
getaddrinfo("daniel-nas.computer", "80", &hints, &infoAddress);
struct sockaddr_in *ipAddress = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>&infoAddress->ai_addr);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipAddress->sin_addr.s_addr, IP, sizeof(IP));
WSACleanup();
```

`IP` is globaly defined: `char IP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];`
**Is there anybody else who came over this issue?**

Comment: What do you mean with your dynamic dns?

Comment: @Wimmel As far as I got a dynamic IP that changes every 24 hours, I got an dynamic dns (`daniel-nas.computer`) which is pointing to my dynamic address. This dynamic dns is updating once very 24 hours. And that's the address I'm passing to `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: ok, so this a dynamic dns service provided by your provider. I think that should work (if you can also use the hostname in other software on your pc). I don't know why it does not work for you.

Comment: @Wimmel Altough the service is not provided by my provider, it is working fine. I'm using it for my NAS, my website and other stuff. But if I'm passing it to `getaddrinfo()`, I just receive `0.0.0.0` as IP address.

Comment: What do you get back if you try nslookup / dig on the DNS name you're looking up? What flags are you passing getaddrinfo?

Comment: @PhilLello If I'm looking it up with `nslookup`, I receive my correct external IP.

Comment: Are you passing AF_INET and walking the list of returned addresses? What does getaddrinfo() return as an exit code? A sample showing the call would really help, feel free to anonymise the nodename if it's hard-coded.

Comment: @PhilLello I'm passing `AF_INET`, but I'm not walking through the returned addresses. Should I do that? `getaddrinfo()` returns `0` as exit code.

Comment: @PhilLello I tested a walk through, but there is no additional IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solution]**
As a kind of solution, I'm using the function `gethostbyname()`. Nevertheless I'm not really pleased with it, because the function is deprecated, but I'm now able to get my IP. Therefore I think, the issue is either my code, although I can resolve other hostnames, or the combination of the function `getaddrinfo()` and DDNS.